# .where query not outputting records that don't have association records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Version**

- Ruby on Rails 4.1.0
- Ruby 2.1.2

**Schema**

- Question has many Answers
- Question has one User
- Answer has one Question
- Answer has one User
- User has many Questions
- User has many Answers

Question and Answer has boolean field, `flagged`

**Goal**

Eager load Question with Answers (and its association, User) and User, with the condition of `flagged = false` for both Question and Answers.

**Query Used**

`Question.includes(:user, answers: [:user]).where(flagged: false, answers: { flagged: false })`

**Problem**

The query only returns Questions that only have Answers associated to it. Questions without an Answer association are not returned. Expected that all Questions that aren't flagged to be returned, regardless of the existence of an Answer(s) associations.

Answer (score 0):

Well... After being stubborn and playing around with the code for a bit I found a solution.

The following query will return Question records that match the flag condition or those which don't have an Answer association

`Question.includes(:user, answers: [:user]).where(flagged: [false, nil], answers: { flagged: [false, nil] })`